# Connection String for LocalDB (.mdf) not working on WPF

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, data-access

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\name\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DBSample\DBSample\Database1.mdf");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Account", con);
SqlDataReader rd= cmd.ExecuteReader(); ;
```

This is my code for connecting to `database1.mdf` but it is not working.

I saw other post that this should already work

Comment: Got any exceptions? "but it's not working" is not useful.

Comment: We need more details to answer your question. You get any exception or error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not opening the connection,you need to open connection with databases before executing query.

do like this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\name\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DBSample\DBSample\Database1.mdf");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Account", con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader rd= cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

**Explanation:**

Other examples you read probably use an **SqlDataAdapter** which opens the connection for you. If you use an **SqlCommand** directly, however, you need to open the connection yourself.

Comment: Explanation: Other examples you read probably use an `SqlDataAdapter` which opens the connection for you. If you use an `SqlCommand` directly, however, you need to open the connection yourself.

Comment: thanks for adding explanation..@ThorstenDittmar

Comment: Thanks :) It works, I did not know about SqlDataAdapter
Edit: Is it possible to make the AttachDbFilename relative?

Comment: if you put .mdf in the app_data folder of application you can pass relative path like this: AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\persondb.mdf

Comment: I don't understand, it does now work. This is the directory result "c:\users\name\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DBSample\DBSample\bin\Debug\Database1.mdf"


UPDATE: I Remove the app_data folder and it work
and error :A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC shar

Comment: Yeah, by the way I tried removing it in app_data and it work. The DataDirectory directs me in the project folder already :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not providing any details on what exact `Exception` you are having, I'll go with the obvious: your connection has not been opened by the time you attempt to execute your SQL query. Not only that but your objects never gets disposed of either.

A better implementation would be this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\name\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DBSample\DBSample\Database1.mdf"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Account", con))
    {
        // here the connection opens
        con.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // do your data reading here
        }
    }
}
```

The `using` statement will make sure your `con`, `cmd` and `rd` objects gets disposed of properly.

Comment: Thanks :) your implementation is better than the common practice

Comment: @FranzJustinA.Buenaventura actually common practice should be to always dispose of objects implementing `IDispose` interface when they're no longer needed, but you are quite welcome.